# renderTable Runs Twice Due to Filter Dependency

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently working on a Shiny app that includes two selectInput elements, where one's choices depend on the selected value of the other. Specifically, the 'period' selectInput's choices depend on the 'granularity' selectInput.

Here's the simple code to illustrate the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
        inputId  = 'granularity',
        label    = 'Granularity',
        choices  = c('year', 'month'),
        selected = 'month'
    ),
    selectInput(
        inputId  = 'period',
        label    = '',
        choices  = '',
    ),
    tableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    generatedData <- reactive({
        n_rows <- 50
        df <- tibble(
            year = sample(
                c(2021, 2022, 2023),
                size = n_rows,
                replace = TRUE
            ),
            month = sample(1:12, size = n_rows, replace = TRUE),
            rand_sample = sample(100:1000, size = n_rows, replace = TRUE)
        ) |>
            arrange(year, month)
        df
    })
    
    # Reactive value to store selected_period
    selected_period <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent(input$granularity, {
        df <- generatedData()
        selected_granularity <- input$granularity
        
        choices <- df |> select(all_of(selected_granularity)) |> pull() |> sort()
        selected <- max(choices)
        
        updateSelectInput(
            session  = session,
            inputId  = "period",
            label    = selected_granularity,
            choices  = choices,
            selected = selected
        )
        
        # Update selected_period
        selected_period(selected)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$period, {
        selected_period_value <- req(input$period)
        selected_period(selected_period_value)
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        selected_granularity <- req(input$granularity)
        selected_period_value <- req(selected_period())
        df <- generatedData()
        message('Rendering a table')
        df_filtered <- df |> filter(get(selected_granularity) %in% selected_period_value)
        df_filtered
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue I'm facing is that the renderTable function in my Shiny app is running twice under the following scenarios:

- When the app initially starts.
- Each time I change the value of the 'granularity' selectInput.

To debug this issue, I've included a message function in the renderTable block to display a log message whenever it's executed. What I've observed is that the log message "Rendering a table" is indeed displayed twice in the console for each of the scenarios mentioned above.

**Expected Behavior:**

I would like the renderTable function to run only once, regardless of whether the app is initially starting or the 'granularity' selectInput is changed.

**Code Analysis:**

I've identified that the issue might be related to how the 'granularity' and 'period' selectInputs are set up and how their reactivity is handled in the server logic. However, I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact problem.

**Request for Assistance:**

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to modify my Shiny app code to ensure that renderTable runs only once, as expected, and to help resolve the issue with the filter dependency between the selectInputs.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: The logic kinda feels all over the place, that's right. :) There is an easy fix if it is an option for you: Just make the output dependent on an Action Button click.
EDIT: The reason why you render the table 2 times is because `renderTable` gets triggered twice: Once by the change of `input$granularity` and once by the update in `selected_period()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue I was facing with my Shiny app, where the `renderTable` function was running twice under certain scenarios, such as when the app initially starts or when changing the value of the 'granularity' `selectInput`. Here's how I fixed it:

The root cause of the issue was related to the data type of the selected values in my app. Initially, the selected values coming from the `selectInput` elements were of type 'character,' while later in my code, I was using them as 'numeric.' This data type mismatch caused the reactivity to trigger multiple times.

To solve this issue, I ensured consistent data types for the selected values by converting them to 'numeric' where necessary using the `as.numeric()` function. Here's the modified code that resolved the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
        inputId  = 'granularity',
        label    = 'Granularity',
        choices  = c('year', 'month'),
        selected = 'month'
    ),
    selectInput(
        inputId  = 'period',
        label    = '',
        choices  = '',
    ),
    tableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    generatedData <- reactive({
        n_rows <- 50
        df <- tibble(
            year        = sample(c(2021, 2022, 2023), size = n_rows, replace = TRUE),
            month       = sample(1:12, size = n_rows, replace = TRUE),
            rand_sample = sample(100:1000, size = n_rows, replace = TRUE)
        ) |>
            arrange(year, month)
        df
    })
    
    # Reactive value to store selected_period
    selected_period <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent(input$granularity, {
        df <- generatedData()
        selected_granularity <- input$granularity
        
        choices <- df |> select(all_of(selected_granularity)) |> pull() |> sort()
        selected <- max(choices)
        
        updateSelectInput(
            session  = session,
            inputId  = "period",
            label    = selected_granularity,
            choices  = choices,
            selected = selected
        )
        
        # Update selected_period
        selected_period(as.numeric(selected))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$period, {
        selected_period_value <- req(input$period)
        selected_period(as.numeric(selected_period_value))
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        selected_granularity <- req(input$granularity)
        selected_period_value <- req(selected_period())
        df <- generatedData()
        message('Rendering a table')
        df_filtered <- df |> filter(get(selected_granularity) %in% selected_period_value)
        df_filtered
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Additionally, I want to highlight that the `reactlog` package massively helped me investigate and debug this issue. It allowed me to trace the reactivity and identify the specific points where the code was being triggered multiple times. If you encounter similar reactivity issues in your Shiny apps, I highly recommend using reactlog as a valuable debugging tool.